# Javascript: How to get text of child element and present them in <p> tag in HTML file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract the information of this XML file and present some of them in `<p>` tag in HTML file.
And my code is here:

Open (this is just the opening code to prepare for my three ways):

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","books.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

star = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book');
var container = document.getElementById('page-wrapper');
var v = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
var autho = y[v - 1].getElementsByTagName('author');
```

Option 1:

```
var text= [];
for (var i= 0, n= y[v-1].childNodes.length; i<n; i++) {
  var child= element.childNodes[i];
  if (child.nodeType===1 && child.tagName.toLowerCase()=='author')
    text.push(getTextContentExceptScript(child));
  else if (child.nodeType===3)
    text.push(child.data);
}
return text.join('');
var pa = document.createElement("p");
var pt = document.createTextNode(text);
pa.appendChild(pt);
container.appendChild(pa);
```

Option 2:

```
var a = 0;
while (a < autho.length)
{
  var t = document.createTextNode(autho[a].textContent);
  var d = document.createElement("p");
  var e = document.createTextNode("Author: " + t);
  d.appendChild(e);
  container.appendChild(d);
  a = a + 1;
}
```

Option 3:

```
for(var k = 0; k < autho.length; k++)
{
  var t = document.createTextNode(autho[k].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  //p_text3 = p_text3 + t + ', ';
  var d = document.createElement("p");
  var e = document.createTextNode("Author: " + t);
  d.appendChild(e);
  container.appendChild(d);
}
```

With those three ways above: I get nothing with option1, the same result with option two that is: Author: [Object Text], [Object Text], ...

Please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the last option this way :

```
for(var k = 0; k < autho.length; k++)
{
    var d = document.createElement("p");
    var e = document.createTextNode("Author: " + autho[k].childNodes[0].nodeValue); // fix
    d.appendChild(e);
    container.appendChild(d);
}
```

It should work. You were atempting to concatenate a string with a `textNode` object...

But we need an XML sample too... Maybe the issue is there.

Comment: @Johnsmith1994 So don't forget to mark this answer as approved if you can... :)